# I am not able to include prebuilt library into android studio

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk, static-libraries

I have written one c++ programme in Ubuntu 16.04 64bit system. I have made its static library. now I have an android studio on Windows 10. I want to import that library into my android project. but I am not able to do that I am getting an error like this...

```
Build command failed.
Error while executing process C:\Users\Parth\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {--build C:\Users\Parth\Desktop\New folder\Octopus\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\x86_64 --target native-lib}
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o
[2/2] Linking CXX shared library ..\..\..\..\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\x86_64\libnative-lib.so
FAILED: cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\Users\Parth\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe  --target=x86_64-none-linux-android --gcc-toolchain=C:/Users/Parth/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/x86_64-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=C:/Users/Parth/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot -fPIC -isystem C:/Users/Parth/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/x86_64-linux-android -D__ANDROID_API__=21 -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -std=c++11 -D__ANDROID_API__=15 -fexceptions -frtti -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a -nostdlib++ --sysroot C:/Users/Parth/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64 -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -LC:/Users/Parth/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/x86_64 -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -shared -Wl,-soname,libnative-lib.so -o 
..\..\..\..\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\x86_64\libnative-lib.so CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o  ../../../../libs/abc.a -llog -latomic -lm "C:/Users/Parth/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/x86_64/libc++_static.a" "C:/Users/Parth/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/x86_64/libc++abi.a" && cd ."
../../../../libs/abc.a(sum.o):sum.cpp:function sum(int, int): error: undefined reference to 'std::cout'
../../../../libs/abc.a(sum.o):sum.cpp:function sum(int, int): error: undefined reference to 'std::cout'
../../../../libs/abc.a(sum.o):sum.cpp:function sum(int, int): error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
../../../../libs/abc.a(sum.o):sum.cpp:function sum(int, int): error: undefined reference to 'std::ostream::operator<<(int)'
../../../../libs/abc.a(sum.o):sum.cpp:function sum(int, int): error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
../../../../libs/abc.a(sum.o):sum.cpp:function sum(int, int): error: undefined reference to 'std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
../../../../libs/abc.a(sum.o):sum.cpp:function mul(int, int): error: undefined reference to 'std::ostream::operator<<(int)'
../../../../libs/abc.a(sum.o):sum.cpp:function mul(int, int): error: undefined reference to 'std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
../../../../libs/abc.a(sum.o):sum.cpp:function mul(int, int): error: undefined reference to 'std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
../../../../libs/abc.a(sum.o):sum.cpp:function __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int): error: undefined reference to 'std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
../../../../libs/abc.a(sum.o):sum.cpp:function __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int): error: undefined reference to 'std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

[image: this is my gradle file]

[image: this is my cMakeLists.text]

Comment: You have defined your API twice:  #define __ANDROID_API__ 15
    
<command line>:2:9: note: previous definition is here
#define __ANDROID_API__ 21

Comment: that's not the problem... I can solve that... the real problem is something else.

Comment: Then please solve the problem first, many problems are indirectly caused by the ones the system complains about before.

Comment: solved it now i am getting this

Comment: And your solution did not change anything about the text seen in the picture you posted?

Comment: Please have mercy with an old mans eyes and post textual information as text, not as picture of text.

Comment: I have changed my Application.mk file... APP_PLATFORM := android-5.  it was  APP_PLATFORM := android-8 and now that API warring is gone but still I am getting the second error as it is

Comment: that image is my cmakeList.txt

Comment: I do not see the screen shots. Not nice.

Comment: screenshot of what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Firstly**, from the screenshot of your library project, you are using ndk together with CMake which does not make any sense. Whatever you configure inside the `.mk` files , i.e. `Android.mk` and `Application.mk`, won't have any effect if you use **cmake**. Try to clean up your project.

**Secondly**, your error logs indicate that your `libstdc++.a` is not in place. Check path `C:/Users/Parth/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64/usr/lib/libstdc++.a` exists or not.

Download ndk from https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r17b-windows-x86_64.zip, unzip it and configure this path inside `local.properties`

```
ndk.dir=<mypath>/Android/ndk/android-ndk-r17b-windows-x86_64
sdk.dir=<mypath>/Android/sdk
```

**Thirdly**, you **HAVE TO** ensure that all your `.a` static libs are compiled using Android CMake tool chains so that they are compatible with your Android.

Comment: thank you, as you said I checked and you are right libstdc++.a does not exist. and  I deleted jni folder so no more ndk in my project. can you help me? what should I do next to solve this?

Comment: you can try to update your NDK from SDK manager to ensure your NDK is complete for the platform version you want to support, i.e. platform 21 in your case.

Comment: I have made a change in my question. and one more thing I want to point it out that I compiled that static library from Ubuntu so want to ask you one question does it work like that? and what if I have an old library and when i try to access that it is said like rand() is missing...  you know in case you know the solution :) I am trying to Update ndk now. I will let you know whaever happened

Comment: No, you HAVE TO compile the .a using Android Cmake tool chains. The one you compiled using Ubuntu Cmake won't be compatible with Android.

Comment: okay, I understood that thanks to clear it out... so suppose if I have some old program which I was using on Ubuntu and now I want to use that programme library (precompiled) is there any way to use it in android and I don't have source code.

Comment: No, it is impossible to directly use the `.a` files compiled from Ubuntu on Android. They are incompatible. So, you need the source code and recompile them using NDK.

Comment: okay, you have edited your answer I got it :) Let me download and I will let you know I fi got an any error

Comment: I have just Downloaded the NDK that you have linked here libstdc++.a   not available in it too. and if I compile with one toolchain in Android and can I import that library when I am using another toolchain. will it compatible?

Comment: I found one strange thing libstdc++.a available but in 19 folder not in 21. so what do i do next?

Comment: xx/Downloads/android-ndk-r17b/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64/usr/lib64/libstdc++.a  I just download and see it here.

Comment: I said no CZ, in the answer that you have edited you have mention "lib" not "lib64". in lib64 i have too

Comment: you are compiling against 64-bit, of course, under path .../arch-x86_64/usr/lib64/... should be the path you need to look for.

Comment: sorry for bothering you, but I have one more question.  if I compile with one toolchain in Android and can I import that library when I am using another toolchain? will it compatible?

Comment: So long as the compilation tool chain is within Android NDK, either CMake gcc or clang++, the lib will work well.